# Block characters are shown in 16x 2 LCD instead of letters while interfacing with atmega328p?

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, c, atmega, embedded

I am trying to display some characters in 16x2 LCD (1602 A) using Arduino Uno (atmega328p-pu). I have written my code using embedded C for 4 bit mode. The code is below.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

#define LCD_DATA_DDR DDRD
#define LCD_CTRL_DDR DDRB
#define LCD_DataBus PORTD  //Using PD4 to PD7
#define LCD_CTRL_PORT PORTB

//function prototypes
void LCD_Write(unsigned char cmd, unsigned char reg_select);
void LCD_WriteData(char data);
void LCD_WriteCmd(char cmd);
void LCD_Init();

void LCD_Write(unsigned char cmd, unsigned char reg_select)
{
  char  tempCmd;
  if(reg_select == 1)
    LCD_CTRL_PORT |= (1<<PB0);   //Select Data Register
  else
    LCD_CTRL_PORT &= ~(1<<PB0);   //Select Command Register

  //Mask data/cmd
  tempCmd = cmd;
  tempCmd &= 0xf0;// mask Lower 4 bits

  //Set data/cmd
  LCD_DataBus &= 0xf0;           //Set PORTD LSB to HIGH since we use PD4 to PD7
  LCD_DataBus |= tempCmd;        //Set bits in PORTD

  //Send data/cmd
  LCD_CTRL_PORT |= (1<<PB1); // Send a High-to-Low pulse at Enable pin
  _delay_ms(400);
  LCD_CTRL_PORT &= ~(1<<PB1); // Send a High-to-Low pulse at Enable pin

  //******Send next 4bits

  //mask data/cmd
  tempCmd = cmd << 4; //shift left 4 times so the LSB bit can be sent.
  tempCmd &= 0xf0; //mask Lower 4 bits

  //Set data/cmd in bus
  LCD_DataBus &= 0xf0;
  LCD_DataBus |= tempCmd;

  //Send data/cmd
  LCD_CTRL_PORT |= (1<<PB1); // Send a High-to-Low pulse at Enable pin
  _delay_ms(400);
  LCD_CTRL_PORT &= ~(1<<PB1); // Send a High-to-Low pulse at Enable pin

  return ;
}

//Send data by setting RS=1.
void LCD_WriteData(char data)
{
  LCD_Write(data, 1);
}

//Send cmd by setting RS=0.
void LCD_WriteCmd(char cmd)
{
  LCD_Write(cmd, 0);
}

void LCD_Init()
{
    LCD_WriteCmd(0x02); // to initialize LCD in 4-bit mode.
    _delay_ms(1);
    LCD_WriteCmd(0x28); //to initialize LCD in 2 lines, 5X7 dots and 4bit mode.
    _delay_ms(1);
    LCD_WriteCmd(0x01); // clear LCD
    _delay_ms(1);
    LCD_WriteCmd(0x0E); // cursor ON
    _delay_ms(1);
    LCD_WriteCmd(0x80); // —8 go to first line and –0 is for 0th position
    _delay_ms(1);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    LCD_DATA_DDR |= 0xf0;  //set the LCD DDRD to output
    LCD_CTRL_DDR |= 0b00000011; //For RS, E

    LCD_Init();
    _delay_ms(30);
    LCD_WriteData('a');
    LCD_WriteData('2');
    while(1)
    {

    }//while
}
```

When I run this C code, I get some white blocks in the upper row, instead of letters.
Then, I ran an Arduino version of LCD code but it worked well. Please tell what am I missing in my embedded c code.

I am using the following pins for LCD interfacing,

- D4 to D7 = PD4 to PD7
- RW = Grounded
- RS = PB0
- E  = PB1

Thank you.

Comment: Your (4-bit) initizalization is not conform the sequence in the HD44780 datasheet. Read it, implement it correctly (including delays) and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your bitwise operations are confused, e.g.

```
  LCD_DataBus &= 0xf0;           //Set PORTD LSB to HIGH since we use PD4 to PD7
  LCD_DataBus |= tempCmd;        //Set bits in PORTD
```

`&= 0xf0` clears the lower four bits of the register (PD0 - PD3). It doesn't do anything to the upper four bits.

What you probably want is `&= 0x0f`, to clear the **upper** four bits before some of them are set in the next line. (Alternatively, if you aren't using the other half of PORTD, consider simply running `LCD_DataBus = tempCmd`.)

Also, for what it's worth, you don't need to delay for 400 ms (!!) while pulsing E. The signal only needs to be high for 450 *ns* (0.00045 ms); any delay will suffice. (If your clock speed is low, you may not need a delay at all.)

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to write your own code ? The [Arduino LiquidCrystal library](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystal) is already working. The initialization of those displays is not easy, because the display could be in 8-bit or in 4-bit mode. The LiquidCrystal library uses a special sequence with commands and delays.

My experience is that even when a working sequence is found to initialize the display, it might fail in some situations. The Arduino LiquidCrystal sequence is found with a lot of trial and error and it is working now.

The source of the LiquidCrystal library with the special sequence is on Github: [LiquidCrystal.cpp](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/LiquidCrystal/src/LiquidCrystal.cpp).

Because the display is slow, there is no need to use direct writing to the output registers. You could use digitalWrite or write your own functions for low level output register writing.

After power up, you should have a delay of about 150ms, because the display is not ready yet.

Answer (score -1):

> Please tell what am I missing in my embedded c code.

your code isn't initializing your lcd properly. compare it vs. the arduino code should help you trouble shoot.